# Cannot open two different web applications in the same browser under the same IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, server, hosting

I'll try to explain this super mysterious behavior to the best of my abilities, I apologize in advance if this is not a Stack overflow question.

I have two applications **App01** and **App02**, both are simple "Helllo World" web applications
They have the following binding:

- App01: 10.0.0.1:80
- App02: 10.0.0.1:2000

If I open any browser and open app01 first, then open app02 in another tap I get a 404 resource not found.

**Conclusion:** I can open the apps in different browsers and even same browser if one of the tabs is anonymous. In the same browser only the first app that I open will work the other will throw a 404.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: IIS applications don't have bindings (as only sites can), so you'd better edit this question to reveal how exactly you configured IIS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: What is the directory structure of App01 and App02 in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

So, we figured out what the problem was. I'll try to simplify this as musch as possible.

If I access App01 the gateway receives the request, fetches the application, and opens a channel. Then if access App02 the browser uses that same channel and is trying to find the application, that explains the 404.

How did we find this? We tested this behavior in IE. **IE opens a channel per tab not per window**.

We fixed it by forcing the gateway to open a chanel per request.